# Upgrade old Xcode Project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I wanted to update one of my older Apps to match the new iPhone Sizes. But I get this error:

> Size metrics for the iPhone 4.7" and iPhone 5.5" may not be used in documents that open in Xcode 5.1 or earlier.

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `.storyboard` or `.xib`.
Show the File inspector, select `"Interface Builder Document" - "Opens in"`, set `"Default (6.0)"`.